# Excel : Data validation - In a table of people, the 'Father' column should only link to male entries

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table of people:

[image]

Note that the field for FATHER offers a drop-down list of people. The list contains a list of all people.

I'd like to have the drop-down list for FATHER only contain people with a gender of 'male'.

What's a good way to set this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way i can think of is to have a second sheet with a filter formula

Create a new sheet and in `A1` use this formula

`=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5="Male","")`

And this formula in `B1`

`=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5="Female","")`

You can now use `='New Sheet Name'!$A:$A` as your source for your drop down

[image]

Giving you the result you're after

[image]

Comment: That's a nice approach. Thanks SQLTemp!

Comment: @dharmatech no worries.